# Is there any PhoneGap View?

Tags: android, cordova

I can create an activity (extending DroidGap class), but is there any PhoneGap View to use it together with my own views in an ordinary activity? I need to use an xml layout for my activity and PhoneGap features together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is being worked on!

Check out this early work and pls give some feedback https://github.com/infil00p/callback-android/tree/cordova_view